# Difference between SQL server express Database

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

My aim is to obtain on Visualstudio 2013 a connection to SqlServer, watching a tutorial I was expecting to have this result:

[image: print1]

but instead I had this:

[image: print2]

Are these 2 database comparable ?
As you can see in my Visual Studio the button to add a SQL Server is unavailable, did I miss something in the installation of SQL Server Express 2014 ?

Thanks for your help.
Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

There are two similar tool windows in Visual Studio...

The Server Explorer

[image]

And the Sql Server Object Explorer

[image]

You can use one or the other to explore Sql Server instances.  Your confusion is because you're looking at one of them (Server Explorer) while expecting it to look like the other (Sql Server Object Explorer)

To view the Sql Server Object Explorer, type that into Quick Launch, or look at the top of the View menu, or type **ctrl-\, ctrl-s**.